# jenkins: error during ant build - java.exe not recognized

Tags: java, ant, build-process, jenkins

I've just started setting up a build server, using Jenkins.

Right now i have an extremely vanilla setup. Just trying to get it to run the default target of a specific build file. However whenever i run it jenkins reports this:

```
[build] $ cmd.exe /C '"ant.bat -file build.xml compileReleaseBuild && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
'"java.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The odd thing is, i have my PATH and JAVA_HOME enviroment variables set up correctly, and i can run this command from the command line correctly. What is it that jenkins does that is different from running the commands by hand?

Comment: Is Jenkins running as the same user as the one that ran your successful command line build ?

Comment: Clever man! That was exactly it, Jenkins is running as system, and i failed to set the system env correctly.

Comment: Can we switch these comments out to an answer and have it chosen? People who are having the same problem as you won't easily find that this has been solved.

Comment: add updates on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by gareth_bowles, Jenkins runs as the system account on your machine. This means that any permissions or configuration (like your enviroment variables) have to be set in the system context as well. ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627296/how-to-get-windows-os-environment-variable-from-system-property) on setting env as the system account)