# How to get Windows OS Environment Variable from System Property

Tags: windows, winapi

I am encountering a strange problem about System Property environment variable.

As you know, we can open `Computer->Property->Advanced System Settings->Advanced->System Environment Variables->User Variables for admin`

I change Variable TEMP' value to C:\mytemp\ and click OK to save it.

However, In command line, when I echo `%TEMP%`, it still show original path, `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp`.

When I input %TEMP% in explorer, it will go to C:\mytemp

Now I want to user API to get the path, `GetEnvironmentVariable()` will also return path which is same as echo %TEMP% in command line. how can I get the path as exploer did. 
Thanks in advance.

PS. OS is Win7 x86

Comment: Yes. restart command line will show new path.
But why use API GetEnvironmentVariable still get the old path not refresh new path, even I restart my process.

Comment: Have you tried restart your IDE instead of just rerun the program?

Comment: IDE? you mean VC compiler? I compile program on PC1, and run program on PC2.

Comment: How about try running your program as admin? (right click and then choose run as administrator)
And have a try to see if situation is the same even system variable is changed instead of user variable

Comment: Even I modify System Variable and run program as Admin, it still get old path as C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp. What happen?

Comment: Modify system variable need a reboot. Try reboot after modifying the system variable and see if it can read new path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing environment path through Computer->Property->Advanced System Settings->Advanced->System Environment Variables->User Variables will take effect immediately. However, please be noted that those programs which are running will not get the latest environment variable.

So I thought that you simply didn't reopen a new cmd for echo.

Open a new cmd, and echo again, the new path will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables are set when the process runs and are not updated.

To verify this, open a command prompt, and type "echo %TEMP%".  Keep the command prompt open and change the %TEMP% variable.  No matter what, entering "echo %TEMP%" will print the old values.

Now open a new command prompt and "echo %TEMP%", the new command prompt will print the new values.

As a workaround, you can spin up a new thread to check the current setting at that particular time.