# Jenkins couldn't recognize Python run from .BAT file

Tags: jenkins, path

I'm a beginner to Jenkins, and trying to run a small Python code from Jenkins batch command for Windows.

However, the build run throws below error:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PythonProject1
[PythonProject1] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins7865401366299588301.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PythonProject1>cd C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\py 

C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\py>python C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\py\for.py 
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\py>exit 9009 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Python is installed in my machine and is declared in Environment Variable too. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

"`Running as SYSTEM`" means the Jenkins service is *not* running with your account, but the [Windows system account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/120929/how-the-system-account-is-used-in-windows), used as a [service account](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66747).

That means you need to add python path to the [system environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18627398/6309), not the user ones.