# Getting “java.net.SocketException: Connection reset with (SSL- Self Signed Certificate)” while invoking API From Jenkins Plugin

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jenkins, keystore

I have a sample Java Program which connects to a particular URL and calls an API that Use Self-Signed Certificate.

The code being called is as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    
        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("https://test1.com/").path("test/AuthorizedUser").queryParam("userName", "abc@test.com").queryParam("Password", "Password1").build();

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.toURL().openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "NoAuth ");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        
        connection.connect();
        
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = response.toString();
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }
```

Above mentioned program is working with Java When I installed SSL Certificate in JVM's trust store using these commands:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\keytool.exe" -import -file "‪C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test1.cer" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\lib\security\cacerts" -alias "Test1_certificate

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\keytool.exe" -import -file "‪C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test1.cer" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -alias "Test1_certificate
```

The problem is that when same code is running from Jenkins Plugin, I am getting this error :

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at com.ssts.restcalls.HTTPClientRestCall.GetInputStream(HTTPClientRestCall.java:92)
    at com.test.restcalls.HTTPClientRestCall.Get(HTTPClientRestCall.java:20)
    at com.test.restcalls.HttpRestCalls.authenticateUser(JerseyRestCalls.java:59)
    at com.test.cloud.aCloud.CloudBuilder$DescriptorImpl.AuthenticateUser(CloudBuilder.java:798)
    at com.test.cloud.acloud.CloudBuilder$DescriptorImpl.checkCredentials(CloudBuilder.java:1060)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$JavaScriptProxyMethodDispatcher.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:490)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$13.dispatch(MetaClass.java:411)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:813)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am unable to figure out what's the problem. Is there is any configuration changes which need to be done in Jenkins.

What can I do to solve the problem? TIA

Comment: Are you using self signed certificate?

Comment: Yes I'm using Self Signed Certificate

Comment: you have https url, are you using httpurlconnection istead of httpsurlconnection on purpose?

Comment: I'm dealing with HTTP or HTTPS both type of URLs that's why i'm using httpurlconnection

Comment: same error is coming with httpsurlconnection too

Answer (score 0):

When it runs in the Jenkins plugin, that means it is loaded and executed on an agent.
Even if that agent was the same machine as the Jenkins main instance:

- the environment can be different
- the JDK used might be different (in which case, the `jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts` modified might not be the same)

You need to check those two points. Each Jenkins job, once executed, has an environment section which can provide more clues.

Comment: I found that the Jenkins jre was located  at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre". I imported the self signed certificate at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\lib\security\cacerts" and executed the plugin but but I am still facing same issue.

Comment: @SachinBhatia You need to check which java is actually launched by your job.

Comment: I tried to fetch java used by Jenkins job by using following code 

System.getProperty("user.dir"); 
System.getProperty("java.home");  

and I'm getting this output  

USER:DIR: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins"
jre_root: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre"

and also imported the certificate at same path but still it gives same error

Comment: @SachinBhatia Is your agent on the same machine than your main Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, Jenkins and agent both is on the same machine

Comment: So chances are the same java is used. Does the main Jenkins runs with the Windows system account? (see links in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608324/6309)

Comment: Jenkins is running as a Windows service

Comment: @SachinBhatia Is it possible, for testing, to run it as your windows account instead of the System one?

Comment: Jenkins service is logon as Local System account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217526/discussion-between-sachin-bhatia-and-vonc).

Comment: Any idea what the resolution was for this?

Comment: @Orb I don't have one for now.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a custom trust store**, add your certificate, and pass that trust store to Jenkins via `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/store` (see [this help](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203821254-How-to-install-a-new-SSL-certificate) for details).

This should resolve any ambiguity about whether you modified the proper system trust store or not. Also, you'll avoid all the risks that come with modifying the system trust store.

Comment: I'm using Jenkins LTS Environment. How can i pass that custom trust store to Jenkins ?

Comment: It's just about passing a standard Java option to the command that you use for starting Jenkins (i.e., unrelated to the actual Jenkins version). How to do that depends on your OS and Jenkins package; if you cannot find the right place, there's a nice overview available at [Cloudbees](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209715698-How-to-add-Java-arguments-to-Jenkins-)

Comment: i created the custom trust store and added my self signed certificate after that I passed that trust store to jenkins at run time but still it gives same error

Comment: If your code runs on an agent, then you need to set the option in the agent startup options (Node options, "Launch agents via SSH" -> "Advanced" -> "JVM Options").

Comment: I'm not using any agent. My Code runs through the master Jenkins node.

Comment: Maybe your definition get overwritten somewhere, or there is some type. Could you double-check the proper definition by entering `println(System.properties["javax.net.ssl.trustStore"])` in Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Script Console?

Comment: I executed the command but I'm getting null value in response.

Comment: That means that your setting of `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/store` is not active. Please double-check for typos and for adding it in the proper place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217893/discussion-between-sachin-bhatia-and-alex-o).